# Mac OS X 10.7.4 Mail Client triggers Opera for external links in email

Tags: safari, mail.app

I would like to have Safari open any links in email messages. However it seems that Opera has hijacked this and I can't see any property that can change this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little counter-intuitive, but you can set the default web browser for email messages from within Safari, just select the Preferences -> General option and then choose an application from the "Default web browser" pop-up menu. Hope that helps.